Google Cloud Uploading distribution asking for Username and Password
I want to create a shared python repository in a GCP project. When I get to upload the dist/*.whl file I am prompted for a username and password, but my pypi account (and gcp account) is Unauthorised.
Following instructions from https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/store-python
gcloud config set project [my_project]
gcloud artifacts repositories create [repo] \ --repository-format=python \ --location=europe-west2 \ --description="Shared Python package repository"
gcloud config set artifacts/repository [repo]
python3 -m pip install --upgrade build
python3 -m build
To confirm the url.
gcloud artifacts print-settings python \ --project=[my_project] \ --repository=[repo] \ --location=europe-west2
I have generated a whl file in the dist folder and running the following command from the root of the project containing the dist folder.
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://europe-west2-python.pkg.dev/[my_project]/[repo]/ dist/*
I am prompted for my username and password. I enter my gcp account details.
Uploading distributions to https://europe-west2-python.pkg.dev/[my_project]/[repo]/ Enter your username: 
In attempt to resolve this I have run revoked and rerun gcloud auth login
You are now logged in as [me@mycompany]. Your current project is [my_project].  You can change this setting by running: $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
I have enabled 'Artifact Registry API' and the repository shows in the list.
gcloud artifacts repositories list
I have the following permissions....
Artifact Registry Administrator (1)
[me@mycompany]
Artifact Registry Create-on-Push Writer (1)
[me@mycompany]
Artifact Registry Repository Administrator (1)
[me@mycompany]
Artifact Registry Writer (1)
[me@mycompany]
I was expecting the dist files to be uploaded to the cloud artifact registry which is listed. I've created an PiPy account and tried my Google Cloud Account to login.
